# How to get ELF executable binaries in Android 5.0 ART

Tags: android, c, reverse-engineering, elf

We are working on [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) mining. We are unable to find path of `ELF` executable in Android 5.0 ART Architecture. 
I currently found `.so` and `.oat` files via Xplore, but these are not ELF executable binaries.

More Detail:
After Android 4.4.4 the Dalvik VM was replaced by ART. In Android 5.0 the DVM's App's dex code was converted to `odex` to get executed. In ART its converted to `ELF` executable code.

I am working on Malware detection software which works by mining `ELF` files to cluster patterns of anomalies. As ART works on AOT compilation so executable binary file (ELF) should exist against each App in internal storage.

My question:
 I want to know the path of the `ELF` file of Apps or some method to obtain `ELF` from `.apk` or `.dex` file.

Comment: Could you post your attempt?

Comment: i found boat.oat file and .so but these are not executable elf binaries

Comment: Which executable?  Android mostly works by forking and loading libraries, exec() is rarely called.  Normally the only executables will be those shipped with the Android installation.

Comment: The poor elves. First they need to do christmas presents, and now they are exploited in mining...

Comment: To clarify, I *think* what @ChrisStratton is trying to tell you is that the `.so` you found *is* the AOT-compiled binary you are looking for - it's just not an *executable*, because the ART VM operates by `dlopen`-ing applications and calling them, rather than `exec`-ing them.  (I don't actually *know* that, though, it's just my interpretation of their comment.)

Comment: Also I would think your analysis would have better luck clustering on the `.apk` or `.dex` or `.odex` or whatever, as those contain strictly more information.

Comment: @zwol - the ART-compiled output is a .oat file, though like a .so it is at least to a degree in ELF format.  The only native code in a typical .apk would be JNI libraries if utilized, while a .odex file does not contain native code either, but only dex code which has been partially digested by and for a Davlik (vs ART) system, by having things like symbolic references resolved.